# Ant debug info not displayed in Processing for Android

Tags: ant, processing

Processing works find, and I can build for Android and run it on my device. However if the code has some compile-time errors in it, like referencing a variable that doesn't exist, Processing tells me this:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:679: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:692: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

There is no info on the location of the error, which is very annoying. 
The only workaround I have come up with is to manually build ANT through the console. In the console, errors are displayed as expected...

I have updated Processing to the latest build 2.03b, and I have downloaded the last version of ANT.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar error due to a typo.  Unfortunately, I do not know a solution to this but may be able to suggest another (better, easier?) workaround.  If you export the project within Processing and open it in another IDE, such as Eclipse, you will see verbose errors and warnings.  I spent a whole weekend before doing this and finding my typo as soon as I opened the project with Eclipse.  Contrary to what the Processing for Android wiki makes Eclipse sound like, using Eclipse is pretty easy (I am not a programmer and have only run the "Hello Android" programs in Eclipse).  Perhaps a more verbose error output will be included in future versions of Processing.  Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, that's a good idea. The verbose errors used to be there, cause I've made many Android apps without problems. But I messed something up in my registry or something and it never came back...